# Getting Error Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003),

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp, ojdbc

Application is configured with Hikari library to manage database connections. Recently upgraded ojdbc jar from ojdbc7 to ojdbc8  and spring jdbc version from 4.3.10.RELEASE to 5.2.9.RELEASE then we are seeing this issue.

Here are hikari cp settings
`MaximumPoolSize = 100`
`MinimumIdle=5`
`IdleTimeout=600000`
`ConnectionTimeout=30000`
`MaxLifetime=600000`
`validationTimeout=25000`

These are the jars configured

`hikari cp =3.3.0` `SpringBoot= 1.5.13.RELEASE` `SpringVersion = 5.2.9.RELEASE` `SpringJdbcVersion = 5.2.9.RELEASE` `ojdbc8 = 19.3.0.0` `SpringJdbcVersion = 5.2.9.RELEASE`

Stack Trace :
`org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed"  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - DataSourceHikariPool - Closing connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3a9e81d8: (connection is broken)"  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - DataSourceHikariPool - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3a9e81d8 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(17008)`

Comment: SQLSTATE 08003 means connection closed, please provide the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I am getting same issue, did you get solution @Mohanrao Kolisetti?